# Call VBA excel macro from word to paste a table that updates based on drop-down list in word

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, ms-office

Here's a good one. First I began to learn VBA TODAY so be gentle. So I have this vba macro in EXCEL 2007 that automatically hides/shows rows in a table based on the user's choice from 3 drop-down menus. FYI, the table automatically updates from a master table that contains all the possible choices by hiding the unwanted rows based on the user's choice. 
Now I want to bring this to another level. What I would want is to be able to call the macro from WORD 2007 so that the table is copied to the word document at a desired location. In order to achieve that, the drop-down menus would need to be in the word document and the EXCEL macro would have to "read" the selected value from the word document to construct the table. In other words, the user would never see the EXCEL part and would obtain a table in his word document based on his choices from the drop-down menus.

I inserted the excel macro that builds up the table. The end result would be such that C1, C2 and C3, which are the variables that drive the IF statements, would be variables from the WORD drop-down menus

```
  Sub Sequence()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ActiveSheet.Cells.EntireRow.Hidden = False

    If Range("C2").Value = 2 Then
        Rows("48:67").Hidden = True
    Else
        Rows("48:67").Hidden = False
    End If

    If Range("C3").Value = 2 Then
        Rows("6:7").Hidden = True
    Else
        Rows("6:7").Hidden = False
    End If

    If Range("C1").Value = 1 Then

        Rows("9:12").Hidden = True
        Rows("14:17").Hidden = True
        Rows("19:22").Hidden = True
        Rows("24:27").Hidden = True
        Rows("29:47").Hidden = True
        Rows("48:51").Hidden = True
        Rows("53:56").Hidden = True
        Rows("58:61").Hidden = True
        Rows("63:66").Hidden = True

        j = 1
        k = -2

        For i = 6 To 67
            If Rows(i).Hidden = False Then

                Range("A" & i) = j
                j = j + 1
                Range("B" & i) = k
                k = k + 1
            End If

        Next i

    End If

    If Range("C1").Value = 2 Then

        Rows("9").Hidden = True
        Rows("11").Hidden = True
        Rows("13").Hidden = True
        Rows("15").Hidden = True
        Rows("17").Hidden = True
        Rows("19").Hidden = True
        Rows("21").Hidden = True
        Rows("23").Hidden = True
        Rows("25").Hidden = True
        Rows("27").Hidden = True
        Rows("29:31").Hidden = True
        Rows("33:35").Hidden = True
        Rows("37:39").Hidden = True
        Rows("41:43").Hidden = True
        Rows("45:47").Hidden = True
        Rows("48:51").Hidden = True
        Rows("53:56").Hidden = True
        Rows("58:61").Hidden = True
        Rows("63:66").Hidden = True

        j = 1
        k = -2

        For i = 6 To 67
            If Rows(i).Hidden = False Then

                Range("A" & i) = j
                j = j + 1
                Range("B" & i) = k
                k = k + 1
            End If

        Next i

    End If

    If Range("C1").Value = 3 Then

        Rows("9").Hidden = True
        Rows("11").Hidden = True
        Rows("13").Hidden = True
        Rows("15").Hidden = True
        Rows("17").Hidden = True
        Rows("19").Hidden = True
        Rows("21").Hidden = True
        Rows("23").Hidden = True
        Rows("25").Hidden = True
        Rows("27").Hidden = True
        Rows("29").Hidden = True
        Rows("31").Hidden = True
        Rows("33").Hidden = True
        Rows("35").Hidden = True
        Rows("37").Hidden = True
        Rows("39").Hidden = True
        Rows("41").Hidden = True
        Rows("43").Hidden = True
        Rows("45").Hidden = True
        Rows("47").Hidden = True
        Rows("48:50").Hidden = True
        Rows("52:54").Hidden = True
        Rows("56:58").Hidden = True
        Rows("60:62").Hidden = True
        Rows("64:66").Hidden = True

        j = 1
        k = -2

        For i = 6 To 67
            If Rows(i).Hidden = False Then

                Range("A" & i) = j
                j = j + 1
                Range("B" & i) = k
                k = k + 1
            End If

        Next i

    End If

    If Range("C1").Value = 4 Then

        j = 1
        k = -2

        For i = 6 To 67
            If Rows(i).Hidden = False Then

                Range("A" & i) = j
                j = j + 1
                Range("B" & i) = k
                k = k + 1
            End If

        Next i

    End If

    Range("A5:D67").Copy

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

   End Sub
```

Comment: Two suggestions. First, no one here can mind read your code. Two, break your question up into paragraphs - I'm not quite clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to call a macro in Excel from Word?
It that's that case, you can do this in Word:

```
Sub excel()
    Dim excel As Object
    Dim wb As Object
    Dim str As String
    Set excel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set wb = excel.workbooks.Open("D:\Profiles\scklam\Desktop\Book2.xls")
    'Run the macro you want
    excel.Run "test2"
    str = wb.sheets(1).Range("A1")
    Selection.TypeText (str)
    wb.Save
    wb.Close
    Set wb = Nothing
    Set excel = Nothing
End Sub
```

In this example, I do something in my excel and then copy the value of a cell back to Word.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. That is part of what I am trying to do However, I still need to be able to choose from a drop-down menu in WORD. Based on the value chosen from the drop-down in WORD, EXCEL would recognize that choice, the table in excel would be updated and then copied to the word document. Thanks!

Comment: if you want to pass an argument to excel, you can use

`excel.Run "test2", arg`

your subroutine in excel should take an argument